# MYSQL KEY-VALUE PAIR Viability

Tags: mysql, key-value

I am new to MySQL and I am looking for some answers to the following questions:

a) Can MySQL community server be leveraged for a key-value pair type database?

b) Which MySQL engine is best suited for a key-value pair type database?

c) Is MySQL cluster a must for horizontal scaling of key-value based datastore or can it be acheived using MySQL replication?

d) Are there any docs or whitepapers for best practices when implementiing a key-value datastore on MySQL?

e) Are there any known big implementations other than friendfeed doing key-value pair using MySQL?

Answer (score 5):

Any relational database can provide a key-value store, but it's not what they're for: and they aren't good at it, not when compared to native key-value databases like e.g. [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

If your requirements aren't extreme, your best bet would be MyISAM as it's probably fastest and transaction support is not (high) on the priority list of key-value databases.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only doing key-value stuff, you might want to check out [HandlerSocket](https://github.com/ahiguti/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL) for Mysql. I haven't used it, but [this overview](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html) shows installation and usage. Basically, it strips out all the relational stuff (query parsing, joins, etc) and uses mysql's storage directly, making it extremely fast (but suitable only for key-value storage).

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the game here, but actually, MySQL version 5.6 has some changes that allow it to become a key value store with memcached built in. It looks really slick:

[NoSQL Interface via memcached](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html)

Comment: Link is broken I think. Just takes you to the general MySQL page.

Comment:  Thanks for doing that.